# How to disable SharePoint:FormField validation in .aspx form?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have custom SharePoint 2010 List and custom aspx form to create, display and edit items in this list. List is defined as:

```
<Field Type="User" Name="Analyst1" Required="TRUE" . . ./>
<Field Type="User" Name="Analyst2" Required="TRUE" . . ./>
<Field Type="User" Name="Analyst3" Required="TRUE" . . ./>
```

in schema.xml.

According fields in DevEdit.aspx are defined as:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="FormFieldAnalyst1" FieldName="Analyst1" ControlMode="New"/>
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="FormFieldAnalyst2" FieldName="Analyst2" ControlMode="New"/>
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="FormFieldAnalyst3" FieldName="Analyst3" ControlMode="New"/>
```

The list logic does not require to fill all fields when creating new list item and some of the "analyst" fields can be specified latter or by other users. My problem is that when I click "Save" in "new item" form, I get "You must specify a value for this required field." error message for such fields what were left blank.

I know, I can manipulate attribute "Required" in the list schema and not set to "TRUE" for every analyst field, but I have to. What I need is a temporary disabling of FormField elements validation in code-behind before actual saving the list item. I have tried following C# code:

```
List.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
List.Fields["Analyst2"].Required = false;
List.Fields["Analyst3"].Required = false;
List.Update();
List.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

in Page_Load() method, but without success. Blank fields are still validated when Save is clicked and "You must specify ..." message is displayed. What I can do? How to disable validation in code-behind for specific fields?

Thanks in advance.